# Rotating a CALayer from a start angle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I want to rotate a layer continuously using `byValue`, but I can't make it work correctly.
I want to rotate by 6 degrees every second, to have a full rotation in 60 seconds.

If the initial rotation of the layer is 0, everything is OK.

The problem is when I try to set an initial `fromValue`. If I set the `fromValue` to 90 degrees, the animation will rotate from 90 to 90+6, then jump to 90+(90+6), animate, and jump again.

Any idea?

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI_2];
animation.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:6.0f*M_PI/180.0f];
animation.toValue = nil;

animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.cumulative = YES;
animation.additive = NO;
animation.repeatCount = 10000;
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
animation.duration = 1.0;
[myLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (DegreesToRadians (90), 0, 0, 1);
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transform];
animation.duration = 60;
animation.cumulative = NO;
animation.repeatCount = 10000;
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
```